# Websocket subscriptions and co-routines: Extracting message without exiting loop?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm trying to organize my real-time subscriptions to an API, this is what I have so far:

```
async def real_time_info():
    channels = ['channel1']
    msg_subscription = msg.public_subscribe(channels)
    async with websockets.connect(URL) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(msg_subscription))
        while websocket.open:
            subscription = json.loads(await websocket.recv())
            return subscription #HERE IS THE PROBLEM I'M TRYING TO SOLVE


async def real_time_data():
    channels = ['channel2']
    msg_subscription = msg.public_subscribe(channels)
    async with websockets.connect(URL) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(msg_subscription))
        while websocket.open:
            subscription = json.loads(await websocket.recv())
            return subscription #HERE IS THE PROBLEM I'M TRYING TO SOLVE


async def main():
    info = asyncio.create_task(real_time_info())
    data = asyncio.create_task(real_time_data())

    while True:
        print(await info)
        print(await data)

asyncio.run(main())
```

So what I want to do is that everytime there is a message from `real_time_info()` or `real_time_data()`, to print it. The problem is that because I'm using return it automatically exits the function and of course stops fetching the messages from the websocket.

I could technically do this by putting it all in a single function and doing all inside of it without the need of exiting the for loop, but then is a whole mess and really difficult to manage the messages I'm fetching from the socket.

Is there a way to get those socket messages out of my `real_time` functions to main, while they still run in a loop?

Thanks!

Edit: I will also ask another questions about websockets that might render all this trivial. Right now I'm connecting to 2 channels of the same API (channel1 and channel2) via 2 different functions. But because in both of them I try to read the messages from the server via `await websocket.recv()`, do these messages still get mixed in the same "receiver"? If so, is there a way to manage responses from servers via websockets? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an instance of `asyncio.Queue()` to your async functions and replace `return subscription` with `await queue.put(('channel1', subscription))`. Then your `main` can look like this:

```py
async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    info = asyncio.create_task(quote_info(queue))
    data = asyncio.create_task(trades_info(queue))

    while True:
        channel, subscription = await queue.get()
        print(channel, subscription)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new to asyncio so didn't know about the Queue method. Do you know if creating 2 separate subscriptions but using the same receiver `websocket.recv()` helps to manage the messages? Or because it's just one pool I could have both channels in just one function with no difference? (See my edit in the OP) P.S.: I edited in the OP the `quote_info` and `trade_info` names since I forgot to do it in the first place and might cause some confusion.

Comment: @Hiperfly Honestly I don't know the answer to the websocket-specific question.